# Downloaded Newest RStudio (1.4.1717) and R files are no longer associated with RStudio and I can't find RStudio in my Programs folder

Tags: r, windows, dataframe, rstudio

Also, on a windows 10 machine and R version 4.1.0.  Since I can't find RStudio on my machine when it asks what program I want to use to open my code files, I just have to go to through the file menu to open the code file.  It's obviously not a big deal, but quite annoying. One of my coworkers is having the same problem after downloading the new RStudio version too, so I'm wondering if it's a bug...or I'm to bug.

Comment: Can you change the [default file associations](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-change-file-associations-in-windows-2624477) for your files? Are these .R files or .Rproj files? If you think it's a bug with the installer, you should report the problem to https://community.rstudio.com/ or https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues

Comment: Possibly this was already reported and was a problem in Windows: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/3970

Comment: @MrFlick they are .R files.  Code/script files. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: The windows update they are saying will fix the issue is a windows update from 2018 (November 27, 2018—KB4467682 (OS Build 17134.441)) and I updated my windows this morning, so I'm wondering if it's the same or similar bug popping up again.